# What does "twice as many" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the paragraph below, what does *Twice as many campaigns...* and *turn customers off* mean?

> Twice as many campaigns are for lead gen as customer retention (84% vs. 43%), so make sure you start with the audience, on every campaign. Approaching longtime friends as if you're perfect strangers can actually turn customers off.
>
> — [Marketing Professionals website](http://www.marketingprofs.com/articles/2014/26439/12-tips-to-help-you-conquer-your-direct-marketing-campaign-challenges)

Comment: Apart from the final sentence this is gibberish to me. *Turn customers off*, means 'cause them to be uninterested in your product'.

Comment: @WS2 thanks, I want the meaning of Twice as many campaigns

Comment: The meaning of *turn off* can be looked up [in a dictionary of your choice](http://www.onelook.com/?w=turn+off&ls=a). The meaning of *twice as many* is explained *right after it in the very same sentence*.

Answer (score 2):

The cited text appears to be about the best way to handle a marketing campaign.

'Lead gen' must be an abbreviation for 'lead generation'.

"Twice as many campaigns are for lead gen as customer retention" means that for every one campaign which is designed to keep hold of existing customers ('customer retention'), there are two campaigns which are intended to generate leads (i.e. to uncover marketing opportunities among people or companies that are not existing customers).

As WS2 implies, *to turn one's customers off* is to actively — though presumably inadvertently — discourage them from buying your products.

Comment: can I edit question to add another question?

Comment: @user123 - The site rules discourage asking multiple questions in the same posting. Ultimately, though, it's your decision whether to amend an existing question or to ask a completely new one. In this case my answer is the only one so far, but you should bear in mind that changing the question after several people have already answered what they thought was its final version is likely to annoy them when they find that their answers now look half-hearted or incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer in the cited text: **"84% vs. 43%"**. That's what "twice as many means". 
As for "can turn customers off, it "can make customers lose interest".

"There were five birds in one cage. In the other one, twice as many. (which is 10)